# Parse XML using namespace prefixes in syntax for root elements - Java

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xml-namespaces

I have an `XML` of the form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<semseg:Envelope xmlns:semseg="http://a-random-URL" xmlns="http://another-random-URL">
    <semseg:subject>Subject</semseg:subject>
    <semseg:Sender>
        <semseg:name>Me</semseg:name>
    </semseg:Sender>
    <Triangle>
        <Triangle time='2017-11-29'>
            <Triangle key='a' value='b'/>
            <Triangle key='c' value='d'/>
            <Triangle key='e' value='f'/>
            <Triangle key='g' value='h'/>
        </Triangle>
    </Triangle>
</semseg:Envelope>
```

And I am trying to retrieve the element `<Triangle>` (*not* `<Triangle time='2017-11-29'>` - element names are a bit repetitive in this XML) using `XPath`. Part of the code is the following:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = documentBuilder.parse("file.xml");

XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xPath = xPathFactory.newXPath();
XPathExpression xpr = xPath.compile("/semseg:Envelope/Triangle");
NodeList nodes = (NodeList)xpr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

I have tried many possible combinations for the `XPath` without any luck unfortunately since no elements are selected. Nevertheless, testing the same `XPath` with [this](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output) online `XPath` checker and the same `XML` file yields exactly the results I am looking for. It evens works for attribute retrieval using XPaths like

```
/semseg:Envelope/Triangle/Triangle/@time
```

Seems like there is a problem with the namespace prefixes. Parsing `XML`s without any namespace prefixes works just fine with `XPath`.

Comment: Have you had a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020638/xpath-parsing-of-namespace-declarations and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939636/how-to-use-xpath-on-xml-docs-having-default-namespace ?

Comment: I think you can try this, " //Triangle[not(@*)]" as your xpath

Comment: @reflexdemon this does not work unfortunately

Comment: @GPI I cannot really use a namespace context since the prefix is only applicable to some of the elements in the XML. You can see that `Envelope` does have such a prefix but `Triangle` does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML input actually has two namepsaces.

#### Default namespace

The first is the default one, declared as such :

```
<semseg:Envelope ... xmlns="http://another-random-URL" ...
```

Being the default one, any XML element that has no namespace on it belongs to this default namespace.

### semseg namespace

Defined as such :

```
<semseg:Envelope xmlns:semseg="http://a-random-URL" ...
```

Meaning every XML element prefixed with `semseg` belongs to this namespace.

### Translating your requirements

So you're aiming at an XPath expression that will target

- any `Triangle` element (no prefix, so that actually translates to **any `Triangle` element from the `http://another-random-URL` namespace**).
- That is a direct child of a root `semseg:Enveloppe` element (that actually translates to a **root element of the local name `Enveloppe` belonging to the "http://a-random-URL" namespace**).

### Programming this in XPath.

We create a NamespaceContext that describes what namespaces we are working with :
I define prefixes that I wish to work with, and map them to the namespaces. These prefixes will be used by the XPath engine. I map :

- The `main` prefix to the `http://a-random-URL` namespace
- The `secondary` prefix to the  `http://another-random-URL` namespace

Using this mapping that I defined, I can translate your requirement to this XPath :

```
/main:Envelope/secondary:Triangle
```

And this works :

```
XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xPath = xPathFactory.newXPath();
xPath.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceContext() {
    @Override
    public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
        if ("main".equals(prefix)) {
            return "http://a-random-URL";
        }
        if ("secondary".equals(prefix)) {
            return "http://another-random-URL";
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {
        // This should be implemented but I'm lazy and this sample works without it
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
        // This should be implemented but I'm lazy and this sample works without it
        return null;
    }
});
XPathExpression xpr = xPath.compile("/main:Envelope/secondary:Triangle");
NodeList nodes = (NodeList)xpr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
System.out.println(nodes.getLength());
```

Outputs :

```
1
```

Here I have implemented a really dumb namespace context, but if you hava Spring framework, CXF, guava (I think), or other frameworks at reach, you often have something like `SimpleNamespaceContext` or `MapBasedNamespaceContext` that are probably better options.

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me

`/\*[local-name()='Envelope']/\*[local-name()='Triangle']/\*[local-name()='Triangle']/@time`

Comment: This does work but I was looking for something more elegant and concise that's why I upvoted it but did not mark it as an accepted answer . Thanks a lot though!